# Вывод данных из MySQL по категориям

Tags: php, mysql

Есть база данных, в ней 2 таблицы(category_sklad состоящая из id name и products_sklad состоящая из id name kolvo category_id). Собственно вот что планируется сделать, например есть красный количество 100 и категория краска.    Как сделать следующее: при выборе категории идет перенаправление на другую страницу и в ней распечатывается таблица со всеми товарами, которые имеют id краска. Выбор категории осуществляется так:

```html
 $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM category_sklad";
 $result_select1 = mysql_query($sql1);
 echo "<select name='category_id'>";
 while($object1 = mysql_fetch_object($result_select1)){
  echo "<option value = '$object1->id' > $object1->name</option>";
 }
 echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял, то достаточно написать на странице вывода по категории (например cat.php) следующее:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['category_id']))
    exit();

$cid = striptags($_GET['category_id']);
//Защита от команд внутри строки

//Рекомендую не использовать расширение mysql, так как оно устарело
//Вместо него используйте mysqli или pdo_mysql
//$db = mysqli("host", "login", "pass");
//$db->select_db("db_name");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products_sklad WHERE category_id=$cid";
$result = $db->query($sql);
while($line = $result->fetch_object()){
    //Вывод объекта, как он вам нужен
}
?>
```

Так же в лендинге следует дописать (index.php или index.html например):

```
<!-- Предположим, что страница, где отображаются товары категории называется cat.php -->
<form action="/cat.php" method="GET">
    <select name="category_id">
        <?php
            $query = "SELECT * FROM category_id";
            $result = $db->query($query);
            while($object = $result->fetch_object())
                echo "<option value=".$object->id.">".$object->name."</option>";
        ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

В SQL запросе имеется возможность указывать фильтры на основе выражении после "WHERE", т.е. в данном примере, если ячейка category_id в записи таблицы products_sklad совпадает с подставленым значением из $cid, то эта строка включится в результат

Comment: Сделал все также, вышла ошибка Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\xamppp\htdocs\kaat\cat.php on line 20

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался   <?php
 if(!isset($_GET['category_id'])){
  exit();
 }

 $cid = strip_tags($_GET['category_id']);
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM products_sklad WHERE category_id=$cid";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 while($line = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
  echo "$line->name <br>";
 }
?>